# Soundcloud update profile description http api

Tags: api, http, soundcloud

I'm trying to update my profile description field through http api...

i'm requesting the /me endpoint using PUT and passing a encoded json as a body with the description and the description value.

I get 200 response status but the description doesn't update.
Also, the response returns my user object in json or xml, depending of endpoint format I'm using.

So, everything works perfectly, besides the fact that the endpoint doesn't accept the format I'm sending or... I have no idea.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Head over to https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication -- it's implicitly documented:

```
import soundcloud

# create a client object with access token
client = soundcloud.Client(access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')

# update the user's profile description
user = client.post('/me', description='I am using the SoundCloud API!')
print user.description
```

See? *"update the user's profile description"*